# Twilio - Python Exception while sending SMS - Udacity Tutorial

Tags: python, sms, twilio

I followed the `Udacity` tutorial for `Twilio` and I get an exception as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaushiksekar/Documents/Programs/Python/send_text.py", line 10, in <module>
    from_="+14066234282") # Replace with your Twilio number
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/twilio/rest/resources/messages.py", line 122, in create
    return self.create_instance(kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 365, in create_instance
    data=transform_params(body))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 200, in request
    resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 164, in make_twilio_request
    uri=resp.url, msg=message, code=code)
TwilioRestException: 
[31m[49mHTTP Error[0m [37m[49mYour request was:[0m

[36m[49mPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{{ AC142b2a041b9695a2e7d73572cd7989b0 }}/Messages.json[0m

[37m[49mTwilio returned the following information:[0m

[34m[49m[0m

>>>
```

Code:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = "{{ authorization sid copied correctly from the site }}" # Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "{{  authorization token copied correctly from the site  }}"  # Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(body="Hey this is a Test SMS",
    to="+919551771607",    # Replace with your phone number
    from_="+14066234282") # Replace with your Twilio number

print(message.sid)
```

Any pointers on what the issue might be?

Comment: Please post the code that caused this error. The exception that was raised is a `TwilioRestException`, which is a "generic 400 or 500 level exception from the Twilio API" according to the docs. So it looks like you made a bad request.

Comment: Are you including `{{ }}` in your account sid and token?

Comment: Yeah I added those braces by mistake. My bad. Thanks anyway

Comment: Is this fixed Kaushnik? If so, would you put the fix in the answer section below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooh, I forgot to remove the braces in while defining the account_sid and auth_token variables. After removing the braces, it's working fine.

Corrected code:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

    account_sid = " authorization sid copied correctly from the site " # Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
    auth_token  = "  authorization token copied correctly from the site "  # Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(body="Hey this is a Test SMS",
        to="+919551771607",    # Replace with your phone number
        from_="+14066234282") # Replace with your Twilio number

    print(message.sid)
```